# Problems with autosizing between 3.5 and 4 inch screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autosize

I have a background image which is the size of a 4 inch screen. When displayed on a 3.5" screen, the top and bottom bits of the image are not shown. However, I have other views, and text boxes on the screen as well that are supposed to line up with the background image, but they don't.

Here are some images of my app:

3.5" screen:

[image: 3.5" Screenshot]

4" screen:

[image: 4" Screenshot]

As you can see, the text box moves slightly further down, than the image does. This is a screenshot of the autosizing settings:

[image: Autosizing Settings]

This is the same for both the background image and the text box. I don't know how I can make the app move the text box down a specified amount or what to do?

If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Auto sizing is helpful until a certain point. The text field is trying to put itself according to the size of the screen, while keeping the bottom's distance ration, which, in your case it's not what you want. My recommendation is:

1. Use auto-layout to specify these rules. It's quite trivial to do this using auto-layout, but can be a bit of a pain to get into Auto-layout
2. Programmatically set the textfield's frame.

Still, try the following:

1. Put the top + left for the `UIImageView`
2. Put left + Right + Bottom for the `UITextField`.

Comment: How can i use autolayout to set different frame origins for 3.5" and 4" screens?

Comment: Perhaps I could set the text field to always stay the same distance from the bottom of the image? how would i do that?

Comment: You create a vertical constrain between the textfield and image.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 should help you starting.